# Gather usage statistics in a web application

Tags: php, usage-statistics

I have a custom Joomla extension that users can purchase, download and install in their own site.

In order to full understand the environment of my customers, I'd wish to gather some statistics about their server configuration and the usage of my extension.

Some important points:

- Data is collect in anonymous way, and this feature is strictly opt-in
- Users could opt-out whenever they want
- No personal information will be ever collected: only server configuration (*Is the PHP function XXX available?*) or my extension usage (*How many records there are in the table XXX?*, *The user ever used the Agenda or the Advanced Search?*)
- Users will be able to review sent data
- The extension is under GPL3 license, so the code is not compiled nor obfuscated
- The extension is not domain specific: once purchased the user could install it wherever he wants (but I'm curious to know the amount of installations)

I made a quick search for any ready-to-use tool, but I couldn't find anything, so I decided to build it on my own.

My biggest concern regards how I can protect myself from malicious users:

- User submitting wrong data on purpose.
- User exploiting the remote server to trigger a DoS attack. I think I'm going to host everything in Amazon web service, so maybe I won't get a denial of service, but it could get *very* expensive

Do you have any suggestions on how I can work around these issues?
Or do you know a tool that I could include in my extension?

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Is the *(hypothetical)* user submitting bad data to your data collection tool on purpose or to the tool that you're selling itself? *or both?*  Is the user exploiting the data collection tool to trigger a DoS?  If any part of it is related to the tool itself, please provide some context so I can more intelligently answer your questions.

Comment: My concern is if a user, after reading the code, start submitting a swarm of fake "reports" to the remote server on purpose

Comment: The first one is very hard, you could try to limit it on the server side e.g.: if you already got statistics from a client disregard connections from that client for a while.
The second one is to make sure that your remote server doesn't send information when a client sends you information then there is no DoS attack to be used.